# Calculate $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{F_k}{2^k}$

Tags: summation, generating-functions, fibonacci-numbers

> Calculate $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{F_k}{2^k}$ Hint: use convolution of
> generating functions

### My try:

$a_i = 2^i$
$b_i = F_i$
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{F_k}{2^k} = 2^{-n} \sum_{k=0}^{n} F_k 2^{n-k} $$
and now let $$c_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n} F_k 2^{n-k}  $$

I know that $<a_n> \bigoplus <b_n> = <c_n>$
So let $$A(x) = \sum_i a_i $$ and similar $B(x)$

$$A(X)B(x) = \sum_{i=0} c_i $$
but I stucked there, how can I finish this task?

Comment: What is $F_k{}$?

Comment: [Fibonacci](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Relation_to_the_golden_ratio), by any chance?

Comment: Assuming that $F_{k}$ is the $k-$th Fibonacci number, it is enough to use the Binet's formula $F_{k}={\displaystyle \frac{\varphi^{k}-\left(1-\varphi\right)^{k}}{\sqrt{5}}}$, where $\varphi$ is the golden ratio.

Comment: How do that without using Binet's formula during calculating? @MarcoCantarini

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you index the fibonacci sequence (i.e. is $F_0 = 1$ or $0$?), you'll have, resp., $$B(x) = \sum_i F_i x^i = \frac{1}{1-x-x^2} \text{ or } \frac{x}{1-x-x^2}$$

Since $$A(x) = \sum_i 2^i x^i = \frac{1}{1-2x},$$
we can multiply and use partial fraction decomposition to write
$$A(x)B(x) = \frac{k_1x+k_2}{1-x-x^2} + \frac{k_3}{1-2x},$$
(for some constants $k_1,k_2,k_3$ you'll need to find) which you can then use to find a simplified expression for the coefficients of $A(x)B(x).$

Comment: Seems like you could just plug in $1/2$ for $x$ in the first formula.

Comment: @hunter That would let you evaluate (assuming convergence) $$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{F_i}{2^i},$$ but it wouldn't tell you its partial sum $$\sum_{i=0}^n \frac{F_i}{2^i},$$ which is what we're trying to evaluate.

Comment: my bad, didn't read the question carefully enough!